# Display the employees name who are completing same number of services in the company

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select Ename ,year(getdate())- year(Hiredate) LenghtOfService 
from Employee
```

I get the employee name and length of service but i dont know how to extract the Ename who has same length of service

Comment: The question is quite unclear, at least to me. Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample?

Comment: I want employee name who has same number of experience                                              1000 Xavior London 1030 2009-02-21 54000 10
1010 John India 1060 2008-04-12 49000 30
1020 Peter India 1090 2009-02-21 74000 40
1030 Smith London 1060 2003-05-23 100000 30
1040 Paul      Stamford 1030 2010-10-10 38000 40

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems want :

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, 
             count(*) over (partition by datediff(year, e.hiredate, getdate())) as LenghtOfService
      from Employee e
     ) e
where LenghtOfService > 1;
```